# "Перипетии"

Tags: этимология

Интересует происхождение слова "перипетии". Приставка "пери-" понятна, а что означает корень?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь нет ни приставки, ни вычленяемого корня, только собственно корень и окончание - да и то переразложенное. Слово целиком заимствовано из греческого

*περιπέτεια - «внезапная перемена в жизни, неожиданное осложнение, трудно преодолимое обстоятельство».*